# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 on Eclipse for Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, dalvik

I know there are many problems like this, but I've followed a bunch of the various solutions with no success.

I am running Eclipse 3.7 on Mac OSX 10.6.8. I have previously worked on Android applications on this SDK and gotten them to compile. But, on my latest project (I had gotten it to compile and run using the Android virtual device when it was in an extremely basic state), when I tell it to Run (to test it out on the virtual device) I get this error message (even though there are no little red X's or anything anywhere in my project or other detectable errors):

[2012-09-01 18:13:48 - RadarGun] Dx 
trouble processing "java/andythompson/radargun/BuildConfig.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-09-01 18:13:48 - RadarGun] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-09-01 18:13:48 - RadarGun] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

-------------------------- (end of error message)-----------------------

I've tried the whole Project->Properties->Build Path->remove all except the one you are working on thing along with the Project->Clean part afterwards.

Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Any other suggestions?

Well, the error message *says* that your code is using a `java.*` or `javax.*` class that it is not supposed to be using.  So try checking your code to find what class it is complaining about.

Comment: I started a new package because I had named my package java.myname.packagename and I guess you can't start with java (I'd seen it on an example online but I guess it was wrong).

Comment: You certainly *shouldn't* start one of your package names with "java." or "javax.".  Those package namespaces are officially reserved for Sun/Oracle classes ... and you might even get into trouble for trademark violation.